# MVC 4 Invoking Actions from buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

**Im new to MVC and I need to know How to invoke Action Methods from a view's buttons. And i need to clarify the difference between button and submit
Thanks**

Comment: Any Sample Code Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons usually belong to a form tag. A form has a submit url. When the button `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` is pressed you are redirected to the url written in form submit. Action Method is tied to a web page. For example if you go to www.eample.com/home/hello you execute Hello action in Home controller.

You can use jQuery to fire AJAX calls to specific pages (for example /home/process) and change the data on the page. To do that you should bind onclick javascript event on the button and there perform ajax call.

Example of AJAX call when page is loaded:

```
function loadContent() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'Page.html',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: sendContent,
        success: successContent,
        error: errorContent
    });
}
function sendContent() {
    ////loading
}
function successContent(data, status) {
    $("#content .main").html(data);
    $("#content").show();
}
function errorContent(request, status, error) {
    ////error
}
$(function () {
    loadContent();
});
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to call action method other than to use java script? Can you please give me an little example?

Comment: You can just click the button and then you will be redirected to another page. HTTP protocol does not allow to arbitrarily send and recieve data. You request a page and then receive the page. No other variant is possible in HTTP. The only variant to request a page without refreshing the current page is via javascript.

Comment: Okay Thanks And will i be able to call a action method in java script function and finally to call that java script function in button's onClick event????

Comment: asp.net allows to write c# code that is then converted to javascript when compiled. But you can always see javascript when debugging a page in a browser. (F12 in Crome)

Comment: Thanks. Have to find about this anymore. Your Ajax call example seems complex. anyway thanks